# Data enter/exit handler

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How is the enter/exit handler evoked in d3.js? I've posted a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UVQxc/3/) and have copied the code over here. I've also posted a couple of pictures for clarity.

[image: When data = [13, 15, 21, 42, 5, 18]]
When `data = [13, 15, 21, 42, 5, 18]`

[image: On transition to data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
On transition to `data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

[image: How it should actually be]
How it should actually be

```js
var data1 = [13, 15, 21, 42, 5, 18],
    data2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    data = data1,
    format = function () {
        var text = arguments[0],
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return text.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number]: match;
        });
    };

var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    innerRadius = outerRadius * .6,
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    donut = d3.layout.pie(),
    arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius);

//Get default settings for a donut chart
var vis, arcs;

vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('class', 'pie');

arcs = vis.selectAll('path').data(donut(data));

arcs.enter()
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('transform', format("translate({0}, {0})", outerRadius))
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr('d', arc)
    .each(function(d) { this._previous = d; })
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        data = data === data1 ? data2: data1;
        arcs.data(donut(data))
       .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween('d', function(a) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this._previous, a);
                this._previous = i(0);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
            });
    });

arcs.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I seem to have solved it partially myself. I've posted a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UVQxc/6/) and copied the code here.

```
var data1 = [13, 15, 21, 42, 5, 18],
    data2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    data = data1, set = 1,
    format = function() {
        var text = arguments[0],
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return text.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
        });
    };

var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    innerRadius = outerRadius * .6,
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    donut = d3.layout.pie(),
    arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius);

var vis, arcs;

vis = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('class', 'pie');

function update(){
    data = data === data1 ? data2: data1;
    arcs = vis.selectAll('path')
        .data(donut(data));

    arcs.enter()
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('transform', format("translate({0}, {0})", outerRadius))
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr('d', arc).each(function(d) { this._previous = d; });

    arcs
        .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween('d', function(a) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this._previous, a);
                this._previous = i(0);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
            });

    arcs.exit().remove();
}

update();
d3.select(window).on('click', function(){
  update();
});
```